# Not able to set value in MUI select

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

hi i m working with reactjs and using MUI select. i m able to select the value but while submission value showing blank

[image]

**Select box**

```
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = React.useState("");
  const handleChangeData = (e: any) => {
  setSelectedOption(e.target.value);
  };
  <Controller
    control={control}
    name="income_slab"
    rules={{ required: true }}
    render={({ field }) => (
      <FormControl variant="outlined" className="control_f">
        <InputLabel htmlFor="outlined-age-native-simple">
          Select Income range
        </InputLabel>
        <Select
      {...field}
          onChange={handleChangeData}
          value={selectedOption}
          inputProps={{
            // name: "age",
          }}
        >
          {incomeSlabList.map((item: any) => (
            <MenuItem key={item.data} value={item.data}>
              {item.name}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    )}
  />
```

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that you use `react-hook-form` since I see a `Controller` component.

The reason why nothing is shown on submission is due to this part:

```
        <Select
          {...field}
          onChange={handleChangeData} <--- here
          value={selectedOption} <--- and here
          inputProps={{
            // name: "age",
          }}
        >
```

By doing so, you override what is contained inside `{...field}` thus the values never get updated inside the form.

A fix suggestion would be to remove these two lines, and fetch the current value through `react-hook-form` with `getValues` if needed.